# How hide a div tag in WordPress 2 weeks after my post was published

Tags: wordpress

I need to hide a div tag Two weeks after my post was published. My Cms is Wordpress. 
I need do this by php codes.  no JavaScript. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have the `div` tag inside your loop. So just get the post date, compare it with current date and do the rest.

Check the following code, if this is what you want then do use it in your code block.

```
function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 ) {

    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    $day = $interval->format('%d');
    $days = (int)str_replace(" Days", "", $day);

    return $days;
}
```

Above is the function and it should be outside loop.

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(get_the_date())) ;
$current_date1 = date('Y-m-d', time()) ;

$days = dateDifference($date1, $current_date1);

if($days > 14 ) {
    // Your code block to hide/show element
}
```

And this above code should be inside loop.

I hope this helps you out :)